# Pandas, Update df1 rows from df2

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have `df1`:

```
id, colA, colB, colC, name
1,  1,  2,  3,  a
2,  2,  3,  4,  a
3,  3,  4,  5,  b
4,  4,  5,  6,  b
```

and `df2`:

```
id, colA, colB, colD, name
2,  10,  20,  D1,  a
3,  20,  30,  D2,  a
```

Is there a way, perhaps using `merge` or `join` to replace the rows in `df` with `df2` matching `id` and `name`

So the result would look like:

```
id, colA, colB, colC, name, colD
1,  1,  2,  3,  a,  N/A
2,  10, 20, N/A, a, D1
3,  3,  4,  5,  b,  N/A
4,  4,  5,  6,  b,  N?A
```

I was thinking something like: `df1.loc[df1.Locident.isin(df2.Locident)] = df2` but that only matches on one column.

Comment: does `df2.combine_first(df1)` work?

Comment: @EdChum oh that's similar to what I want, but I would like to replace specific rows of `df1` with rows from `df2` matching on `['id', 'name']`

Answer (score 0):

You could:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'name'], keep='last').drop_duplicates(subset='id')
```

to combine both `DataFrame`s and keep duplicate `id`s and `name`s that stem from `df2`, and get rid of `id`s from `df2` that you do not want to keep.

Comment: Did this help after all?